# Flutter device list not showing web server

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications

I am developing a flutter web app and when I try to run it on a mobile device it has some bugs so I want to debug it on emulator's browser but when I try to run my flutter web app I don't see web server in `flutter device list`

[image: web server not in device list]

I am finding a way to run flutter web on my IP address

I want to run my flutter web app on an IP address to test it on different devices. But I can't see web server in `flutter device list`

Comment: There is not a device "web server" in devices list, a web server is something regard a web server not a client (Web Browser). If I well understood you want to run your app in a web browser. TO do that just launch your project on a Web Browser is the browser that will go to position on your url specified in project specs (I think will be something like 127.0.1 or localhost or your https://yoursite.com).

Comment: No, I show somewhere that in `flutter device list` we can have  web server from flutter tools

Answer (score 0):

It's there but hidden.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75088

`flutter run -d web-server`

`flutter devices --show-web-server-device`